# How to Use PL/SQL and Dynamic Dates for pivot - New post

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, pivot

I mocked up some test data here below.  Would appreciate your input.  Can really use your help on how to dynamically pivot on the date. I also tempted my first PLSQL code below as well.  It is not quite working.  Can you guys help me out ? so the first part is getting dynamic dates. the second part is pivoting using the variable stored dates.  Do you think this is the right approach?  Really can use some help thank you for your time

```
with t as (
select 27 test_number, 'NCO' src_sys_cd, 'CO' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '06-27-2018' date_without_time, 14 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '06-28-2018' date_without_time, 15 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '06-29-2018' date_without_time, 16 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '06-30-2018' date_without_time, 60 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'I' clm_type_cd, '06-30-2018' date_without_time, 60 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NCO' src_sys_cd, 'CO' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-01-2018' date_without_time, 28 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NCO' src_sys_cd, 'CO' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-02-2018' date_without_time, 70 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NGA' src_sys_cd, 'GA' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-03-2018' date_without_time, 80 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NMA' src_sys_cd, 'MA' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-04-2018' date_without_time, 90 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NSC' src_sys_cd, 'SC' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-05-2018' date_without_time, 100 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NNC' src_sys_cd, 'NC' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-06-2018' date_without_time, 20 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-07-2018' date_without_time, 29 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'I' clm_type_cd, '07-07-2018' date_without_time, 29 rec_cnt from dual
union all
select 27 test_number, 'NHI' src_sys_cd, 'HI' rgn_cd, 'P' clm_type_cd, '07-08-2018' date_without_time, 28 rec_cnt from dual
)
```

Below is the hard coded SQL currently:

```
WITH T AS
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT
              TEST_NUMBER,
              SRC_SYS_CD,
              RGN_CD,
              CLM_TYP_CD,
              TO_CHAR(INSRT_DTTM,'mm-dd-yyyy') AS DATE_WITHOUT_TIME,
              REC_CNT
            FROM result
            WHERE TRUNC(INSRT_DTTM)   >= TO_DATE('05-19-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            AND TRUNC(INSRT_DTTM) <= TO_DATE('05-25-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
          )
        SELECT *
        FROM  T PIVOT 
          ( 
          SUM(REC_CNT)  -- need an aggregate function, since there is only one row, it should be fine
          FOR DATE_WITHOUT_TIME IN ('05-19-2018','05-20-2018','05-21-2018','05-22-2018','05-23-2018','05-24-2018','05-25-2018') )
        ORDER BY
          TEST_NUMBER,
          SRC_SYS_CD,
          RGN_CD,
          CLM_TYP_CD;
```

This is working fine. I want to use the below date function to replace the hard coded dates in the FOR clause.

```
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW') + Level - (1+ TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW') - TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW'))
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY level <= 8;
```

This give me results like :

```
        DATE_WITHOUT_TIME
        02-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        03-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        04-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        05-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        06-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        07-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        08-JUL-2018 00:00:00
        09-JUL-2018 00:00:00
```

I want to replace the hard coded date in the FOR clause using this dynamic date, but I have not done any PLSQL before.  below is my attempt, not quite working.  Can you help out? thanks

```
       DECLARE
  date_time clob ;
  sqlqry clob;
BEGIN  
SELECT DISTINCT 
--    LISTAGG('''' || DT || ''' AS ' || DT,',') WITHIN GROUP (
    LISTAGG('''' || DT || '''',',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY DT)
  INTO DATE_TIME
  FROM
    (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW') + Level - (1+ TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW') - TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW')) AS dt
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY level <= 8 --great
    ) ;
sqlqry:='SELECT DISTINCT
      TEST_NUMBER,
      SRC_SYS_CD,
      RGN_CD,
      CLM_TYP_CD,
      TO_CHAR(trunc(INSRT_DTTM)) AS DATE_WITHOUT_TIME,
      REC_CNT
    FROM CDW_T.DATA_MONITORING_RESULT 
PIVOT 
  ( 
  SUM(REC_CNT)  
  FOR DATE_WITHOUT_TIME IN (@date_time)) 
ORDER BY
  TEST_NUMBER,
  SRC_SYS_CD,
  RGN_CD,
  CLM_TYP_CD'; 

execute immediate sqlqry;
end;

Error report -
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at line 33
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Please tag your database, each database has difference in function & syntax.

Comment: Thank you, it is oracle SQL Developer as client. and BANNER CON_ID
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production" 0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0

Comment: though the code I added to my original post is not right working yet, I got a jump started today on learning PL/SQL.  I may be eating one too big meal at once.  Looking forward to getting some help from you all.

Answer (score 0):

You did all the hard work and was very close to the end. Good job for not giving up! Found out, that in SQL you can't build pivot structures, without knowing all the columns in advanced. That how it works. Got me curious, is it really impossible? PL/SQL to the rescue!

Created a procedure in package, that gives me the result in cursor form. Displaying the package's body:

```
create or replace package body test_pck as

procedure get_cursor(p_cursor out sys_refcursor) is

  l_date_list varchar2(4000);
  l_sql varchar2(4000);

begin

  select
    listagg('''' || tmp.date_without_time || '''',',') 
    within group (
    order by tmp.date_without_time)
  into l_date_list
  from(
    select distinct 
      tmp1.date_without_time
    from
      CDW_T.DATA_MONITORING_RESULT) tmp;

  dbms_output.put_line('date_list: '||l_date_list);

  l_sql := '
    select 
      *
    from(
      select
        tmp1.rec_cnt,
        tmp1.date_without_time
      from
        CDW_T.DATA_MONITORING_RESULT tmp1)
    pivot(
      sum(rec_cnt)
      for date_without_time in ( ' || l_date_list || ' ))';

  open p_cursor
  for l_sql;

exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' - ' || sqlerrm);
end get_cursor;
end test_pck;
```

After calling the procedure in Test mode (PL/SQL feature):

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  test_pck.get_cursor(p_cursor => :p_cursor);
end;
```

The output is:

[image: Output]

Does it help?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.   I don't have the privilege for creating any objects on our servers.  We are business analysts.  IT owns the servers.  They don't want us messing around.  Or maybe the other way around in our mind.   :-)   But I still learn from what you have in the code. thank you.

Comment: @Hanna, glad to help. There is another way, if you need just to analyze data (and if your are good at reading XML structures) - use pivot XML() construction. That way you can do all in just one SQL statement. For example, the pivot part can be written - <..pivot xml(sum(sal) for job in (select distinct job from emp))..> Good luck!